# Replace Numeric Constant in Pandas Panel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panel of data that contains a rolling daily correlation matrix of two identical dataframes with multiple columns. I'd like to calculate some daily descriptive statistics but want to ignore correlation coefficients of 1.0 (since I'm correlating the dataframe with itself) and can't figure out the best way to do so. The replace method doesn't seem to be working for me. How best to go about this?

```
matrix = pd.rolling_corr(df, df, window=60, pairwise=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I gave up and ended up looping through each value and replacing self correlation values with NaN.

```
    def remove_self_correlation(panel):
        for col in panel_columns:
            panel.loc[:, col, col] = np.nan
        return panel
```